# When is .profile executed?

Tags: bash, debian, startup, variable

I was installing an application and had trouble with understanding why the installation guide told to add an `export` command to the one of startup files. I did not see when it is executed.
That was the line:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
```

I executed some code in terminal and figured out that the `export` command did not work. Why?

```
root@localhost:/home/gameboy# echo export ADAM=Boss>>/home/pythontest/.profile
root@localhost:/home/gameboy# tail /home/pythontest/.profile
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
export ADAM=Boss
root@localhost:/home/gameboy# su pythontest
pythontest@localhost:/home/gameboy$ echo $ADAM

pythontest@localhost:/home/gameboy$
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`~/.profile` may be run at the launch of a login Bash shell.

First the system executes the system-wide `/etc/profile`, then the first of these files which exists and is readable:

```
~/.bash_profile
~/.bash_login
~/.profile
```

Your problem is that you're changing user via `su pythontest`. You must ensure that the spawned shell is a login shell by adding the `-l` flag:

```
su -l pythontest
```

Answer (score 1):

You either do `export ADAM=Boss` afterwards for immediate change or `. ~/.profile` to force the shell to re-read the `.profile` file.

Comment: So what for are `.profile` files? I can put my export command to any file and execute it whenever I want. I thought that `.profile` file is run by a system.

Comment: You should read the manual page for your shell.

Comment: In man there is a topic "Invoked as an interactive login shell, or with --login". Is the problem of being an interactive shell? When I use su command bash is not invoked by interactive login shell?